# How to get the specific version of dependency from the spring boot starter packs

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project where we are using gradle:
and we have added the dependency of: `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.5'`

This starter dependency brings the
`spring-security-config:5.6.2` and
`spring-security-web:5.6.2`

But we need the `spring-security-config` and `spring-security-web` version to be ***5.6.9*** and we don't want to upgrade the starter dependency version as well.

I tried setting the `ext['spring-security.version']='5.6.9'`
But it didn't work.

Is there any other way we can achieve this?

Comment: I found this helpful link: https://nexocode.com/blog/posts/spring-dependencies-in-gradle/. You can try that.